# Ejercicio de Logica en JS (Practica)

Tags: javascript

En mi conquista por aprender bien JavaScript intento realizar ejercicios de logica, buscando que junto a js pueda dar soluciones.

he estado estudiando lo relacionado al Frontend y quiero desarrollar la mejor manera para utilizar JavaScript de manera mas eficiente. Tengo el siguiente ejercicio, pero **no me aparece el resultado en consola**. ***Podrian ayudarme a esta solucion para visualizarlo en consola?***

```
/*=============================================
Caso #3  CUATRO PERROS

Tenemos cuatro perros: un galgo, un dogo, un alano y un podenco. Este ultimo come mas que el galgo; el alano come mas que el galgo y menos que el dogo, pero este come mas que el podenco. ¿Cual perro come menos?


Galgo:   
Dogo:
Alano:
Podenco:

==============================================*/

var p = {

    Dogo: 0,
    Galgo: 0,
    Alano: 0,
    Podenco: 0,
    resultado: function(){

        if (p.Podenco > p.Galgo &&
            p.Dogo > p.Alano &&
            p.Alano > p.Galgo &&
            p.Dogo > p.Podenco){

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },

    intervalo: setInterval(function(){

        p.Dogo = Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);
        p.Galgo = Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);
        p.Alano = Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);
        p.Podenco = Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);

        if (p.resultado()){

            clearInterval(p.intervalo);
            console.log('Perro Dogo ', p.Dogo);
            console.log('Perro Galgo ', p.Galgo);
            console.log('Perro Alano ', p.Alano);
            console.log('Perro Podenco ', p.Podenco);
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: No deben cumplir las condiciones del `if`. Si intentas con valores fijos y no random funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No aparece resultado porque las condiciones para que se cumplan las restricciones no se lograran usando un random entre 1-2 (sigue intentandolo sin exito).

Si subes el rango (1-4, por ejemplo) vas a encontrar rapidamente algun caso correcto. Ademas, el intervalo de tiempo puede ser menor para llegar al resultado mas rapido.

```js
var p = {

    Dogo: 0,
    Galgo: 0,
    Alano: 0,
    Podenco: 0,
    resultado: function(){

        if (p.Podenco > p.Galgo &&
            p.Dogo > p.Alano &&
            p.Alano > p.Galgo &&
            p.Dogo > p.Podenco){

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },

    intervalo: setInterval(function(){
        p.Dogo = Math.ceil(Math.random()*4);
        p.Galgo = Math.ceil(Math.random()*4);
        p.Alano = Math.ceil(Math.random()*4);
        p.Podenco = Math.ceil(Math.random()*4);
        
        if (p.resultado()){

            clearInterval(p.intervalo);
            console.log('Perro Dogo ', p.Dogo);
            console.log('Perro Galgo ', p.Galgo);
            console.log('Perro Alano ', p.Alano);
            console.log('Perro Podenco ', p.Podenco);
        }
    }, 100)
}
```